# Cronjob not working as expected - issue with hook?

Tags: cron

Today I've tried to write a Wordpress Cronjob. For testing purposes I wrote a function that sends me an email every hour, but it's not working.
I've got a plugin called 'Core Control' which shows me all existing Cronjobs - mine is also listed there. There is also a button "Run now". If I press it, I get the test-mail, so the function itself is correct.

Here is the code for the Cronjob, it is placed inside the functions.php of my theme.

```
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'check_cron' ) ) {  
   wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'check_cron' );  
}   

add_action( 'check_cron', 'sendit' );

function sendit() {  
    $address = "address@provider.com";
    $sender = "Cron_Test";
    $sendermail = "crontest@sender.com";
    $subject = "It works!";
    $text = "Yay, it is working!";

    mail($address, $subject, $text, "From: $sender <$sendermail>");    
}
```

There has to be something wrong with the action hook, but I have no idea what's wrong. Or do I need to place the code in some different file?

Some more Info:
I now that `mail();` does not work on localhost, that's why I created a test blog online. The folder is protected via .htaccess with a password, could that be an issue?

I also checked that my wp-config.php allows Cronjobs.

I also now that the site needs to be visited for the Cronjob to run.

Comment: Are you on WP 3.3? I have been having troube with `wp-cron` since the upgrade (posts with missed schedule), so maybe it is a general issue.

Comment: Yes I am also on 3.3.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the WordPress cron jobs are only triggered when your site is visited (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)):

> The action will trigger when someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed.

I *believe* this to get around the fact that many on shared hosting aren't normally allowed to set up cron jobs (at least, not without contacting their host first).

Comment: Do you know if the cron job will run in the same request / process as the site visit which triggers it? i.e. will the site visitor who triggers the cron job experience a delay while the wp cron job runs?

Comment: It won't, no. It'll spawn a new one. If that's not allowed, I believe it triggers a http request of the page - that's the 'alternative wp cron', as a bit of hacky workaround for difficult hosts.